# Angular ng-class via ng-click inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

**Edit:** The answers below haven't taken into account the +1 function that is also being applied. Still looking for how I can make both happen.

I have an ng-click function that is called on a button within an ng-repeat, but each time one of the buttons is clicked it causes the class to change on all the buttons.

How can I fix my code to make it so only the clicked button itself changes?

(Keep in mind, the numbers work fine, it's just the classes that change all together.)

The Angular controller code:

```
$scope.activeClass = false;

$scope.addHeart = function(post){

    $scope.activeClass = !$scope.activeClass;

    $scope.activeClass ? post.hearts += 1 : post.hearts -= 1;

};
```

And the HTML:

```
<button ng-class="{'red' : activeClass}" ng-click="addHeart(post)">{{post.hearts | number}}</button>
```

Comment: `activeClass` is accessible globally to all button's . try making it independent based on index .

Comment: You have two options provided in the answers although there could be many more. If none is suitable, edit your post to explain if you have specific needs !

Comment: if in-case you want single selection at-a-time try this https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29445/ .

Answer (score 3):

All of your buttons are bound the same scope variable. So the fact that all of them change is a normal behaviour.

If you only want to do so for the clicked element you should do the following:

```
<button ng-click="addHeart($event)"></button>
```

Now we are sending the event with that click which will enable us to know **which** button has been clicked.

In your scope, add the following to your addHeart function:

```
$scope.addHeart = function($event) {
    angular.element($event.currentTarget).addClass('red');
}
```

This lets you access the current element in the DOM and manipulate it ;)

**EDIT**

Either your question was not clear enough or my interpretation was wrong. Either way, I think I understand your need and we should do this in a different way.

If I understood your comment the right way, you do have the number of hearts in your json feed (or whatever source the posts are coming from).

In that case, you might use `ng-class` with an expression:

```
<button ng-click="addHeart($event)" ng-class="post.hearts > 0?'red':'empty';"></button>
```

I only added the logical test for demonstration purposes. `post.hearts > 0?'red':'empty'` You actually don't need the `> 0` part since 0 means `false`.

We are testing if that post has more than 0 hearts, in which case it should be red. If your two-way-binding works as expected, this should work as well !

Comment: Okay, but if I do this then it breaks the number adding functionality. How can I toggle the class AND add the number at the same time on only one target?

Comment: You may also pass both arguments to the function: addHeart($event, post) {} and do both in there. This is entirely up to you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array and update the flag inside the array for each ng-repeat row.

```
<div ng-repeat="node in nodes track by $index">
   <button ng-class="{'red' : activeClass[$index]}" ng-click="addHeart(post, $index)">{{post.hearts | number}}</button>
</div>
```

Js

```
$scope.activeClasses = [];

$scope.addHeart = function(post, index){

    $scope.activeClasses[index] = !$scope.activeClasses[index];

    $scope.activeClasses[index] ? post.hearts += 1 : post.hearts -= 1;

};
```

Comment: What would the accompanying JS in the controller look like for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y">
  <button ng-class="{'red':applyColor==true,'blue':applyColor==false}" ng-click="applyColor = x.color ? true : false;">
    Change Color
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.