# Update ng-class in ng-repeat using ng-click

Tags: angularjs

How can I update the ng-class when I click the ng-click in ng-repeat?

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y">
  <button ng-class="{'red':color==true,'blue':color==false}" ng-click="changeColor(x.color)">
    Change Color
  </button>
</div>
```

Script

```
$scope.changeColor = function(c){
  if(c){
    $scope.color = true;
  }else{
    $scope.color = false;
  }
}
```

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672968/angular-ng-class-via-ng-click-inside-ng-repeat) but it doesnt work.

UPDATE

I want to change only the color of the button clicked.

Comment: @31piy I update it.

Comment: What's the issue that you encouter? IMO, your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/4ca0uxo7/3/

Comment: x.color is never changing and that's why the initial value of x.color is set to $scope.color

Comment: @31piy I just want to change the color in that button clicked only not all button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that for all the elements in the collection, you're using the same flag, i.e. `$scope.color`. When this flag changes, it changes all the buttons' color.

To mitigate that, one way is to have an array which contains the value `true` and `false` at the specified indices and use that array to decide the class assignment in the template.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.y = [{
    color: 'r'
  }, {
    color: ''
  }];
  
  $scope.classes = [];

  $scope.changeColor = function(c, i) {
    if (c) {
      $scope.classes[i] = true;
    } else {
      $scope.classes[i] = false;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in y track by $index">
    <button ng-class="{'red':classes[$index],'blue':classes[$index] !== undefined && !classes[$index]}" ng-click="changeColor(x.color, $index)">
    Change Color
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd strictly discourage to use `$index`, it could harm if you apply filter over `ng-repeat` collection (`$index` may vary for different filtering criteria) . Rather passing direct object reference would be appropriate IMHO.

Comment: @PankajParkar -- Yes, that's a valid point. Since OP hasn't specified much details of the source object, I had to rely on the index because wouldn't want the original object to change.

Answer (score 1):

You should maintain `color` property on element rather than using global (single) `color` property for styling effect. I'd say pass whole entity `x` to change color method and toggle `color` property when user clicks on it.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y">
  <button ng-class="{'red':color,'blue':!color}" ng-click="changeColor(x)">
    Change Color
  </button>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-repeat="x in y">
  <button ng-class="color ? 'red: 'blue'" ng-click="changeColor(x)">
    Change Color
  </button>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.changeColor = function(c){
   c.color = !c.color;
}
```